# how to show rows as column in mysql view table

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am trying this in code igniter to display the table like this i have to show the average of the company for that years respectively

But now we want to change structure of that and Rows convert into columns.

```
year    avg     company
2015    10         2
2015    50         1
2014    25         2
2013    23         2
2011    56         3
```

now i want my table to look like this

```
year   1    2   3
2015  50   10
2014       25
2013       23
2011           56
```

Comment: Seeing as you have tagged this with php, just handle the display issue there, using a simple loop. I do like it when contributors post diametrically opposite answers as things you 'have' to do.

Comment: actually i want it send to an array for line charts

Comment: That's OK, a well ordered array will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pivot the records for the desired output.

**Example**:

```
SELECT year
     , MAX( CASE WHEN company=1 THEN avg ELSE '' END ) as `Company1`
     , MAX( CASE WHEN company=2 THEN avg ELSE '' END ) as `Company2`
     , MAX( CASE WHEN company=3 THEN avg ELSE '' END ) as `Company3`
  FROM so_q31890405
 GROUP BY year
 ORDER BY year DESC
```

[image]

***SQL Fiddle***: [***Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e9d2/2)

Comment: hi my avg is a function avg(value) as avg

Comment: Show your records on which you calculated `AVG`

Comment: SELECT YEAR( mptd.updated_time ) AS year, avg( mptd.actual_value ) AS avgs, mpr.company_id AS gender
FROM (
`mmt_lab_template_details` mltd   ,     , MAX( CASE WHEN company=1 THEN avg ELSE '' END ) as `Company1` i want to do like this

Comment: @ShabazSheikh Consider amending your original question with this VITAL piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql unfortunately doesn't have support for pivot tables.  You have to solve this on the PHP side.

Load your data in three variables so that they contain :

```
$companies = [1,2,3];
$years = [2015,2014,2013,2011];
$averages = [
    2015 => [1 => 50, 2 => 10],
    2014 => [2 => 25],
   ... 
];
```

Then you can write the table :

```
echo '<table><tr><th>year<th/>';
foreach ($companies as $company) 
    echo "<th>$company<th/>";
echo '<tr/>';
foreach ($years as $year) {
    echo '<tr><td>$year<td/>';
    foreach ($companies as $company) 
        echo "<td>{$averages[$year][$company]}<td/>";
    echo '<tr/>';
}
echo '<table/>';
```

Answer (score -1):

The Query is :

select year, avg(sum(company)),count(company) from companymaster group by year;

Comment: No. One possible query would be SELECT * FROM companymaster ORDER BY year DESC, company, `avg`;